# Is it possible to use Spring MongoTemplate to do an update that does a push to a sorted array?

Tags: spring, sorting, push, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

Does anyone know how to use `MongoTemplate.findAndModify` to push an element to a sorted array?

It doesn't look like `MongoTemplate` supports the update `$sort` operator.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/

Answer (score 1):

Support for `$push $each` with `$sort` is currently not available for `Update`. Please see [DATAMONGO-1141](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1141) for progress on this issue. Meanwhile you could use `BasicUpdate` to create the statement you need.

```
Update update = new BasicUpdate(new BasicDBObject());
update.push("yourFieldNameHere", new BasicDBObjectBuilder()
  .add("$each", Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"))
  .add("$sort", 1).get());
```

will create

```
{
  "$push": {
    "yourFieldNameHere": {
      "$each": ["foo","bar"],
      "$sort": 1
    }
  }
}
```